# Kubuntu system updates, terminal vs software center

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, kubuntu

I had some issues a while back with Kubuntu 18.04.2 LTS after I installed it. I mixed and matched updating my system from the terminal and the software center and it caused multiple issues with my drivers, my system performance, and a few applications.

I remember the basic Linux update commands as:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

However, I was also notified the software center wanted to update my system as well. Are they the same update procedures? If that is the case, is it safe enough to only use the terminal and ignore the software center just for system updates? If they are different, how, and should I use one over the other for updating my system?

Also, should I be doing `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` before `sudo apt-get upgrade`, or does it even matter?

Comment: dist-upgrade updates your current OS version so you only needed sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade to update

Comment: What is "my drivers"? Where did you get them, how many, what for, etc? What is "update my system"?

Comment: @wraith3690001 By OS version, you mean my system would be upgraded from 18.04.02 LTS to 19.xx? If that is so, wouldn't it matter when I update my entire system vs all the packages that run on the system? I guess I'm searching for the wrong way to do this, so I can avoid making mistakes. What series of actions using these update/upgrade method might break something?

Comment: @mikewhatever Generic and specific drivers come with the distro like nvidia-intel hybrid display drivers, generic bluetooth and WiFi, etc... But I don't see them as quite relevant to the question. I'm just curious what might be the best way to upgrade/update my system's software pages and OS version. Is there a wrong way to do it that might break something or cause performance issues?

Comment: yes you will upgrade from 18.04-19.xx like I said to update your system software and packages do only the two commands sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade running the command sudo apt-get dist-upgrade will break things and btw your software centre/update manager will use those two command

Comment: @wraith3690001 So, why will it break things? Am I never supposed to use that command? If the software center can do those things, then I can completely ignore it and be totally safe doing everything in the terminal right? (Oddly enough, I'm more comfortable with the terminal than the software center)

Comment: you can use the command to upgrade your os build but drivers are not just distro specific but build specific as well i.e. 18.04 vs 19.04 and this may also apply with certain software for example different build versions may use different python builds or drop that software in place of something newer like when linux mint dropped mdm in place of lightdm and so on. but yes you can update in the term i do it often just avoid dist-upgrade unless you want to upgrade os builds

Comment: @wraith3690001 `dist-upgrade` does not upgrade to the next version. On Debian systems, it can be used for that purpose after editing `/etc/default/sources.list`, but on Ubuntu that method is unsupported and likely to cause severe package conflicts. The `dist-upgrade` command may be used to perform a more complete package upgrade than `upgrade`, but it should be done cautiously since it may remove packages.

Comment: @Zanna oh my bad (－‸ლ) thnx for informing me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-get` and Software center are just different front-ends for the same procedure. There are even more options like [`aptitude`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_(software)) or [Synaptic](https://dev.to/xeroxism/how-to-install-synaptic-package-manager-in-ubuntu-linux-hm3).

> If that is the case, is it safe enough to only use the terminal and ignore the software center just for system updates?

Yes, after you upgrade your packages using the terminal, the Software center should stop offering to update until new updates arrive.

> I mixed and matched updating my system from the terminal and the software center and it caused multiple issues with my drivers, my system performance, and a few applications.

You must have some other problem in your packages management system like mixing packages from different releases or even distros. You can [start a new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) about that but please be more specific (which drivers? which applications? how the system performance was affected?) and perhaps provide the contents of your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and the contents of the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` directory (if any).

> Also, should I be doing `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` before `sudo apt-get upgrade`, or does it even matter?

No, `dist-upgrade` is stronger than `upgrade`, you can read it in [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) (emphases mine):

> `dist-upgrade`
>      **In addition to performing the function of `upgrade`**, this option also intelligently handles changing dependencies with new versions of packages; (…) **The `dist-upgrade` command may therefore remove some packages.**

So you can use `dist-upgrade` if you are not worried about removing packages (and carefully check the list of packages to be removed before proceeding). There is also no reason to issue `upgrade` after `dist-upgrade`, since it’s contained already.

> I remember the basic Linux update commands as:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get upgrade
> sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
> ```

By the way, not all Linux distros use these commands, they are specific to Debian and its derivatives (including Ubuntu and the derivatives of it), other Linux distros can use `yum`, `pacman` and maybe others.